Tire tube is preventing tire from sitting properly
The part without the valve fits nice.

The part with the valve bulges out a bit.

I deflated them and moved the tire aside. It looks like the tube is preventing the tire from sitting correctly.

I tried my best to move it, but unlike the rest of the tube, it is not easily moved. Of course, I loosened the valve screw and tried to tuck it in under the tire, but it didn't work.

Should I push it up with the tire deflated?
Will this cause any problems down the road (pun intended)?

(By the way, is there a way to reply to answers?)
I got it to fit by applying a ton of upward force to the valve, pushing it all the way in, as well as pinching the top of the tire and lots of wiggling. Thanks to everyone who helped!

Not sure I understand the problem properly, but if it is what I think, then it may help to gently pump the tube up, just so that it becomes tubular, and only then reattempt seating the tyre.

Okay, I'll try that, thanks

With the tube slightly inflated, it may be hard to get the tire on the rim. Make sure that the edge of the tire sits in the middle of the rim, where the rim diameter is smaller, so you can get the tire on more easily.

The tire bead must seat firmly on the rim, without pinching the tube. The way it is now is a recipe for flats.
To fix the problem you have, you need to:

Loosen the nut on the valve stem almost all the way off.

Make sure the tube is almost completely deflated.

Push in the valve stem such that the tube goes entirely inside the
tire.  It is important that no portion of the tube comes between the tire bead and the rim.

Seat the tire bead firmly on the rim, making sure the valve stem is coming straight out from the rim, and is not tilted.

Fill the tube to final pressure.


Only then can you snug up the valve nut, but do so only lightly.  Or even discard the valve nut altogether so that you won't have this problem in the future.  The valve nut is helpful for protecting the valve from stresses during pumping, but not absolutely necessary.
